# Function isn't returning desired value

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a VBA function that reads the 11th row of another worksheet and finds the minimum value on the row.

However, the minimum's absolute value must be less than 100. (The row displays both percentages and regular values and I only need the minimum percentage.)

Here is what I have so far:  (it has only returned a value of zero)

```vb
Function Loss(worksheet1 As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim min As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myRight As Long, Colcount As Long

    min = 0

    myRight = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For Colcount = 1 To myRight
        If (ActiveSheet.Cells(11, Colcount) > min) And Abs(ActiveSheet.Cells(11, Colcount) <= 100) Then
            min = ActiveSheet.Cells(11, Colcount)
        End If
        Exit For
    Next Colcount
End Function
```

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjNYk.png)

Comment: you have previously asked this question in a different format. Why not add a picture to illustrate what you are saying and want?

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot take a screenshot of the file because it is confidential information. I can however explain in detail what I need the code to do.

Comment: The idea is that I have a sub that copy the data for each workbook linked in column B.
I want to automatically fill column I using this function

Comment: I added a link to the photo

Comment: Two observations: 1) you use ActiveSheet rather than worksheet1 throughout - is that correct? 2) You're not returning anything - you'll need to have `Loss = min` at the end or similar.

Comment: thanks, but it's still returning a value of zero

Comment: The `Exit For` statement means that the `For` loop will only run once and then exit. Try removing that

Comment: Thanks, now it is only returning a value of 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination of:

```
min = 0
```

and:

```
If (ActiveSheet.Cells(11, Colcount) > min) And Abs(ActiveSheet.Cells(11, Colcount) <= 100) Then
```

looks like it would find the **maximum** value of the data between 0 and 100. If the maximum data value is less than 0 then it looks like 0 would be returned.

There is a more subtle error in the right-hand part of the comparison:

```
Abs(ActiveSheet.Cells(11, Colcount) <= 100)
```

We know from the question narrative that you want this clause to return True for cell values from -100 to 100 inclusive and False otherwise. It actually returns True for cell values less than or equal to 100 and False otherwise - so, for example, a cell value of -198 would make this clause return True.

What this clause should say is:

```
Abs(ActiveSheet.Cells(11, Colcount)) <= 100
```

We need to take the absolute value of the cell and then compare that to 100. Previously, we were comparing the original value of the cell to 100 (which would result in True or False) and then taking the absolute value of True or False (which doesn't change anything - True stays True and False stays False).

To find the minimum value of the data then `min` needs to start at 100 and the comparison needs to be `.Cells(11, Colcount) < min`.

Putting all of this together with suggestions in the comments from bobajob and me gives us:

```
Option Explicit

Function Loss(worksheet1 As Worksheet) As Double

Dim min As Double
Dim i As Integer
Dim myRight As Long, Colcount As Long

min = 100

With worksheet1
    myRight = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    On Error GoTo err_handler

    For Colcount = 1 To myRight
        If (.Cells(11, Colcount).Value < min) And (Abs(.Cells(11, Colcount).Value) <= 100) Then
            min = .Cells(11, Colcount).Value
        End If
    Next Colcount

    On Error GoTo 0
End With

Loss = min

Exit Function

err_handler:

Select Case Err.Number
' Type mismatch
Case 13:
    With worksheet1.Cells(11, Colcount)
        MsgBox "Error in column " & Colcount & "; with value " & .Value & "; of type " & TypeName(.Value)
    End With

    ' Stop running the macro
    Stop
' For all other errors, just stop
Case Else:
    ' Stop running the macro
    Stop
End Select

End Function
```

Additional notes:

- I've added [Option
  Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement)
  as the first line to require variables to be declared. This needs to
  go at the top of the module before any Subs or Functions
- I've specified the `Value` property each time we look at a cell value.
  Whilst `Value` is the default property of a Range object, I prefer to
  specify which property is being accessed explicitly
- If row 1 of the worksheet being checked doesn't have the same number of columns
  as row 11 of that worksheet then you may get incorrect results. This is
  because we are calculating `myRight` on row 1 but then reading data
  from row 11
- I changed the return type of the function from `Long` to `Double` to
  match the data type of `min`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help ! it's much appreciated. however this function is giving me a mismatch error on the following line: 
`  If (.Cells(11, Colcount).Value < min) And (Abs(.Cells(11, Colcount).Value) <= 100) Then`

any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: is it possible that this is due to the fact that you set the function to be a double instead of a long ?

Comment: It's likely that one of the values you are looking at cannot be converted to a number. I've updated my code with some error handling to locate both the source and the reason for a type mismatch. The variable `min` was already a Double so changing the function return type wouldn't affect that line

Comment: Hi, I no longer have the mismatch error however the function is only returning a value of 100. I cant seem to understand why it isn't returning the minimum